# Can I average out a constant (intercept) in OLS regression?

Tags: regression, least-squares, intercept

I have a OLS regression in the form:

$$Y_t=\alpha +\beta X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}$$

Can I average out the constant during the OLS estimation/derivation and report,

$$y_t=\beta X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_{t}$$

Could I explain this as "I have averaged out the constant during the OLS procedure?"

So the intercept is there, the estimation procedure I use (code I have) averages it out, is there some correct technical jargon for this?

Comment: Did you mean centre the data before running the regression?

Comment: Yes, I did!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: See the third answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201919/utility-of-the-frisch-waugh-theorem

Comment: @ZarinaAkhtar so i mean, unless I'm missing something, that's what it's called. You mean centred the data so the intercept=0. Your residuals should still be ok.