# Interpretation of a 0 $R^2$

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression

I know that if the coefficient of determination $R^2$ is 0, then the estimated regression line is horizontal. However, in the case of multiple regression, how would you show that $\hat \beta_0=\bar y$ and $\hat \beta_1 = ...=\hat \beta_p=0$, assuming that $\hat y=Z\hat \beta$ where $Z$ is a $n\times(p+1)$ matrix

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

When all the other regressors except the intercept are zero, you effectively only regress on a constant. What are the fitted values of that regression? What are then the residuals $e$?

How does the $R^2$, defined as
$$
R^2=1-\frac{e'e}{(y-\bar{y})'(y-\bar{y})},
$$
then look like?

Comment: I just realized that Z should be $nx(p+1)$. I think in this case $e'e=(y-\bar y)'(y-\bar y)$ ?

Comment: also would all the fitted values $\hat y$ just be $\bar y$ ?

Comment: Indeed, see, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201919/utility-of-the-frisch-waugh-theorem. The desired result then follows directly, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: welcome  - if your question has been answered, please consider clicking on the check mark to indicate it has been dealt with