# Derivation of residual bivariate expression to find the value for a multiple linear regression coefficient

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, causality

Could someone help me with this derivation? How do I get to this expression of $k$?

$y_i=\beta_0+kT_i+\beta_1X_{1i}+...+\beta_kX_{ki}+u_i$

$k = \frac{Cov(Y_i, \tilde{T_i})}{Var(\tilde{T_i})}$

where $\tilde{T_i}$ is the residual from a regression of all other covariates $X_{1i}+...+X_{ki}$ on $T_i$.

Comment: have a look for "Frisch-Waugh-Lovell theorem", see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201919/utility-of-the-frisch-waugh-theorem/201942#201942