# Rescaling in within transformation - Fixed effects model

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, plm

I have been studying fixed effects models recently and I am stuck at within transformation.
According to my understanding the dependent and independent variables are demeaned wrt clusters and regressed giving us the estimates. How do we rescale the variables as the estimates are obtained for the demeaned values.
Also please do tell me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: No need to rescale due to demeaning. The coefficients you get are the ones taking fixed effects into account. You might want to look at the FWL theorem and its application in panel data context, e.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201942/94889

Answer (score 0):

They are typically not rescaled