# A close-form solution to a low dimensional curve fitting

Tags: curve-fitting, approximation

I have a very short vector of intensities (let's say 5 elements per vector). The intensities are a discrete sampling of a curve around its maxima (the maxima is not discrete though). What I'd like to do then is to use those entires to approximate the curve and find the actual maxima. Yet, I cannot use an iterative algorithm, so I'll have to find something with a close form solution. Any suggestions?

I experimented a bit with the comments from
[Getting a second-order polynomial trend line from a set of data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71187/getting-a-second-order-polynomial-trend-line-from-a-set-of-data)
but it didn't seem to provide correct results.

Thanks